# Woocommerce shop page only categories

Tags: woocommerce

I'm working on Woocommerce and my shop page is showing subcategories AND products.

I've tried ticking check boxes in woocommerce catalog preferences to show only categories but it's not working. Also my theme doesn't have any option to shop only categories.

Any help ?

My site is www.tvaltonen.com/fysiomyynti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new page "MyShop" with this code:

[product_categories number="12" parent="0"]